# Joining multiple date fields to calendar table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, calendar, qliksense

I have a table, let's call it Records, where the relevant data is organized as such:

```
| Employee | SubmissionDate | FirstReviewDate | SecondReviewDate |
  Anne       2017-10-02       2017-10-03        2017-10-10          
  Bernard    2017-10-03       2017-10-05        2017-10-10
  Charlene   2017-10-06       2017-10-09        2017-10-09
  Danielle   2017-10-02       2017-10-03        2017-10-09
  Anne       2017-10-03       2017-10-03        2017-10-09
```

Every time an employee makes a submission, a new entry is added with a SubmissionDate. The record is later edited to include then the first and second reviews take place.

I also have a calendar table called Calendar with a field called TheDate which has dates for every day this year. What I would like to do is associate SubmissionDate, FirstReviewDate, and SecondReview date with Calendar.TheDate so that I can do a count for all three fields for any given day.

I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT Employee,
       Count(SubmissionDate) AS "Submissions",
       Count(FirstReviewDate) AS "First Reviews",
       Count(SecondReviewDate) AS "Second Reviews"
  FROM Records
  LEFT JOIN Calendar ON Records.SubmissionDate = Calendar.TheDate
   AND Records.FirstReviewDate = Calendar.TheDate
   AND Records.SecondReviewDate = Calendar.TheDate
 WHERE TheDate = '2017-10-11'
```

All of the variations of this I have tried output nothing:

```
| Employee | Submissions | First Reviews | Second Reviews |
```

My desired code would look like this:

```
SELECT Employee,
       Count(SubmissionDate),
       Count(FirstReviewDate),
       Count(SecondReviewDate)
  FROM ???
 WHERE TheDate = '2017-10-03'
```

where ??? would be the proper join. Using the desired code block (including the where clause), the desired output would like this for the example data provided:

```
| Employee | Submissions | First Reviews | Second Reviews |
  Anne       1             2               0
  Bernard    1             0               0
  Charlene   0             0               0
  Danielle   0             1               0
```

I am not sure how to do this join. I have read many resources about calendar tables, but the examples always include joining tables that each have a single date identifier. My problem is that I have one table with three date fields that need to be associated with Calendar.TheDate.

I am arranging my data like this so that the data can be visualized in Qlik Sense. I would like users to be able to select TheDate from a filter panel and have it aggregate all three fields for the date specified (essentially identical to the WHERE clause in my example code).

Comment: would help if you display sample data and result.

Comment: My sample data is at the top, and I mentioned it output nothing. I will try to edit the post to make this more clear.

Comment: will need to see the desired result and not based from what you've tried.

Comment: I have updated my original post to include some more example data as well as the desired output. I apologize; I realized what you were asking for after I responded. Let me know if there is anything else I can add for clarity.

Comment: based from the desired result and raw data .. how did you come up with Anne having 2 first review dates?

Comment: Whenever a document is submitted, a new record is created along with the SubmissionDate. In the example data, Anne has two records, one submitted on October 2nd and the other on October 3rd. Both records have a FirstReviewDate of October 3rd. I have added an explanation of the Records table for clarity.

Comment: Anne has 2 submissions and 2 reviews.. but in your desired output Anne has only 1 submission

Comment: My desired code block has a where clause that reads: WHERE TheDate = '2017-10-03'. I will update my post to draw attention to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
create table #recs (
  Employee varchar(10), 
  SubmissionDate date, 
  FirstReviewDate date, 
  SecondReviewDate date
)

insert into #recs values
('Anne',       '2017-10-02', '2017-10-03', '2017-10-10'),          
('Bernard',    '2017-10-03', '2017-10-05', '2017-10-10'),
('Charlene',   '2017-10-06', '2017-10-09', '2017-10-09'),
('Danielle',   '2017-10-02', '2017-10-03', '2017-10-09'),
('Anne',       '2017-10-03', '2017-10-03', '2017-10-09')

select Employee
    , sum(IIF(SubD.Date_Value = #recs.SubmissionDate, 1, 0)) AS Submissions 
    , sum(IIF(SubD.Date_Value = #recs.FirstReviewDate, 1, 0)) AS [First Reviews]
    , sum(IIF(SubD.Date_Value = #recs.SecondReviewDate, 1, 0)) AS [Second Reviews]
from #recs
    left join DimDate SubD on SubD.Date_Value = '2017-10-03' and
        (SubD.Date_Value = #recs.SubmissionDate
        or SubD.Date_Value = #recs.FirstReviewDate
        or SubD.Date_Value = #recs.SecondReviewDate)
group by Employee
```

If your SQL Server is older than 2012, use CASE instead of IIF

```
select Employee
    , sum(case when SubD.Date_Value = #recs.SubmissionDate then 1 else 0 end) AS Submissions 
    , sum(case when SubD.Date_Value = #recs.FirstReviewDate then 1 else 0 end) AS [First Reviews]
    , sum(case when SubD.Date_Value = #recs.SecondReviewDate then 1 else 0 end) AS [Second Reviews]
from #recs
    left join DimDate SubD on SubD.Date_Value = '2017-10-03' and
        (SubD.Date_Value = #recs.SubmissionDate
        or SubD.Date_Value = #recs.FirstReviewDate
        or SubD.Date_Value = #recs.SecondReviewDate)
group by Employee
```

Comment: Thanks again; I have marked your response as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work - I've included some simple DML for sample data:-

```
--Table Setup
IF OBJECT_ID('Records') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE Records;
IF OBJECT_ID('Calendar') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE Calendar;

CREATE TABLE Records (
  Employee varchar(100),
  SubmissionDate datetime,
  FirstReviewDate datetime,
  SecondReviewDate datetime
)


CREATE TABLE Calendar (
  TheDate datetime
)

INSERT Records
  VALUES ('Anne', '2017-10-02', '2017-10-03', '2017-10-10'),
  ('Bernard', '2017-10-03', '2017-10-05', '2017-10-10'),
  ('Charlene', '2017-10-06', '2017-10-09', '2017-10-09'),
  ('Danielle', '2017-10-02', '2017-10-03', '2017-10-09'),
  ('Anne', '2017-10-03', '2017-10-03', '2017-10-09')


INSERT Calendar
  VALUES ('2017-10-03'), ('2017-10-04'), ('2017-10-05')



--Main Query
DECLARE @TheDate datetime = '2017-10-03'

SELECT
  Employee,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN c1.TheDate IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END),
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN c2.TheDate IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END),
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN c3.TheDate IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END)
FROM Records r
LEFT JOIN Calendar c1
  ON r.SubmissionDate = c1.TheDate
  AND c1.thedate = @TheDate
LEFT JOIN Calendar c2
  ON r.FirstReviewDate = c2.TheDate
  AND c2.thedate = @TheDate
LEFT JOIN Calendar c3
  ON r.SecondReviewDate = c3.TheDate
  AND c3.thedate = @TheDate
GROUP BY Employee
```

Comment: This code works to my specifications. Thank you very much for your response, I have upvoted the response (although it is not publicly visible).